# Javascript: select random element from array that is not equal to 'undefined'

Tags: javascript

I have an array that has only had specific keys set. The array will look something like

```
arr[0] = 'undefined';
arr[1] = '16';
arr[2] = 'undefined';
arr[3] = '13';
arr[4] = 'undefined';
arr[5] = 'undefined';
arr[6] = '24';
arr[7] = 'undefined';
```

From that particular array I would want to randomly select either 16, 13, or 24.

Is there a good way to do this?

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a new array consisting of the *indexes* of the entries of your original array that you wish to consider (e.g. `{1, 3, 5}` in your case); then pick a random element (in whichever way that satisfies your statistical requirements) from the index array and then retrieve the corresponding value.

Answer (score 2):

The 'best' way of doing this would be to randomly select one element in a loop. Exit the loop if the selected element is not "undefined".

Comment: This is potentially very inefficient if you have a huge array where most values are "undefined".

Answer (score 1):

First I would loop through the array stripping out the `undefined` values. Then pick an element from the resulting array.

Answer (score 1):

Randomly select one index and from that index search for a non-undefined element.

```
function getrandom(arr){
    var ri = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);

    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
      var ai = (i + ri)%arr.length;
      if(arr[ai] != 'undefined'){
         return arr[ai];
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
arr = arr.filter(function (n) { return n !== undefined });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function randomFromTo(from, to){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from);
}

var Arr = // You define this
var answer = 'undefined';
while (answer == 'undefined'){
     answer = Arr[randomFromTo(0, Arr.length)];
}
```

Thanks to http://www.admixweb.com/2010/08/24/javascript-tip-get-a-random-number-between-two-integers/

Answer (score 0):

```
(function( src ) {
    console.log( src[ ~~(Math.random() * src.length) ] );
}( arr.filter(function( elem ) { return elem !== 'undefined'; }) ));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/y7g6x/

This is slightly tricky. What basically happens is, that the array is first filtered for all non 'undefined' values. That new array is then passed into the self-invoking function where we just call a `console.log()` on a random element. We need to make sure that our call to `Math.random()` does not deliver some floating point value, so I'm using `~~` to cut numbers. Its probably more convinient to use `Math.floor()` there.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way that is unbiased, doesn't create a temporary array and only scans the array once. It's based on [reservoir sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling).

```
function pick_random_value(src)
  local count = 0
  local value = undefined
  for( i=0; i<src.length; ++i)
  {
    if (src[i]==='undefined') { continue; }
    ++count;
    if ( Math.random() < 1/count ) { value = src[i]; }
  }
  return value;
end
```

The downside is that `Math.random()` gets called multiple times. There may be ways to reduce that number of calls though.

An upside is that it can be modified to select N unique items rather than just one easily.